# How to access a row using FlatList keyExtractor in react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to access a row using key, set using keyExtractor in FlatList.

I using FlatList inorder to populate by data, i need to get a row separately using it's key, inorder to update that row without re-render the entire view.

on **componentWillMount** i populated datalist array using an api call.

dummy array look this

> [{id:"Usr01",title:"Name1"},{id:"Usr02",title:"Name2"},...]

while press on any row i get it's id, i need to access that row using it's key.

> let dataitem = this.state.datalist[id];

while i console dataitem i get undefined

i set id as the key in keyExtractor, is there any way to do the same.

My code look like this

**FlatListScreen.js**

```
export default class FlatListScreen extends Component { 
constructor(props)
{
super(props);
this.state={
    datalist: [],
}
}

componentWillMount() {
ApiHandler.getlistitem('All').then(response =>{
    this.setState({datalist: response});
});
}

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

_onPressItem = (id) => {
let dataitem = this.state.datalist[id];
const { name } = dataitem
const newPost = {
    ...dataitem,
    name: name+"01"
}

this.setState({
    datalist: {
        ...this.state.datalist,
        [id]: newPost
}
})
};


_renderItem ({ item }) {
    return (
    <MyListItem
    id={item.id}
    onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
    title={item.title}
    />
    )
} 


render() {
return ( 

<FlatList
    data={this.state.datalist}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
/>


    );
}

}
}
```

**MyListItem.js**

```
export default class MyListItem extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        id: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    const { title, id } = this.props

    this.setState({ title, id })
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { title, id } = nextProps

    this.setState({ title, id })
}


shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { title} = nextState
    const { title: oldTitle } = this.state
    return title !== oldTitle
}
render() {
    return (
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.props.onPressItem({id:this.state.id})}>
        <View>
        <Text>
            {this.props.title}
        </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think changing

`onPressItem({id:this.state.id});`

to

`onPressItem(this.state.id);` in your child component

OR

```
_onPressItem = (id) => { }
```

to

```
_onPressItem = ({id}) => { }
```

in your parent component will solve the issue.

As you are sending it as an object from child to parent and you can access it like this also

```
let dataitem = this.state.datalist[id.id];
```